# What's the relationship between these processes?

Tags: statistics, complex-systems

**A snow ball rolling down a mountain:**
It's surface area gets bigger, thus the ball collects more snow until it can't hold it's own weight anymore.

**Two hot dog stands are next to each other:**
If one has a substantially bigger line than the other and you know nothing about any of the stands, you'll pick the one that's more corwded because that probably means it's better. That is, until you reach a line so long that makes you pick the other.

**Adquisition of wealth:**
People with higher levels on income can get better positions through upper class networking while people with low income more often than not are offered low paying positions. This process doesn't seem to reach equilibrium in the short term, unlike the other two.

Are these examples part of a bigger set of problems? Which branch of math deals with these type of stuff? My best guess would be statistics but I think it may mix with complex systems too.

Comment: In all three examples, you have a positive feedback. Dynamic systems theory deals with stuff like this.

Comment: It does seem related to population dynamics type stuff but I feel like there's something missing, I don't doubt that dynamical systems could model these things but the behavious seems like an emergent property of something to do with the arrangement of the bits and pieces that make up these scenarios, I'm wondering what do they all have in common other than the current state of the system being dependent of the previous.

Comment: The positive feedback. This is dynamical system lingo and means that the rate of change of a state increases with the actual value of the state. The line gets bigger because it's already big. The bigger the snowball, the faster it even gets bigger. The richer you are, the more chances you have to get even richer. Similar: population growth proportional to population size; atomic chain reactions; corona virus; increasing sales saves money by scale effects, so you can reduce prices which again increases sales which saves money...

Comment: Thank you very much :)